# Table - Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

Tags: errors

What is the real problem with this table?

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c }

B & F & P & C &  $B \lor F$ & $P \lor C$ & $\neg(F \land C)$ & $\neg(B \land P)$
T & T & T & T & T & T & F & F \\ % Error l.37 T & T & T & T & T & T & F & F \\ ?
T & T & T & F & T & T & T & F \\
T & T & F & T & T & T & F & T \\
T & T & F & F & T & F & T & T \\
T & F & T & T & T & T & T & F \\ 
T & F & T & F & T & T & T & F \\
T & F & F & T & T & T & T & T \\
T & F & F & F & T & F & T & T \\
F & T & T & T & T & T & F & T \\
F & T & T & F & T & T & T & T \\
F & T & F & T & T & T & F & T \\
F & T & F & F & T & F & T & T \\
F & F & T & T & F & T & T & T \\
F & F & T & F & F & T & T & T \\
F & F & F & T & F & T & T & T \\
F & F & F & T & F & T & T & T \\
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

Comment: You're missing a ``\\`` at the end of the first row.

Comment: @dcmst: See [Formatting Sand-Box](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3150/5764) and [this comment](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208/formatting-sand-box#comment8717_208).

Comment: I see you're not following my suggestions about using `array`, `\True` and the similarly defined `\False`. By the way, you're using “F” in apparently two very different meanings, which can be utterly confusing. In the first line you have “B” and the other variables appearing with different shapes, adding to confusion.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In addition to inserting the missing `\\` line break instruction, you should contemplate undertaking the following steps:

- Implement fully the suggestions @egreg made with regard to [your earlier posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202998/5001), inluding the use of `array` instead of `tabular` and the use of macros rather than hard-coded letters for "True" and "False". (Do also think hard *why* you're using the letter `F` both as a variable and as the token for "false". Is it so difficult to come up with a better variable name than "F"?)
- Get rid of all vertical bars, and use the line-drawing macros of the [booktabs](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package to insert a few but well-spaced horizontal lines.
- Add a bit of extra vertical whitespace *after every fourth row* in the body of the table, since four rows at a time provide a natural grouping for the table at hand.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\T{\textrm{T}}  % "true"
\newcommand\F{\textrm{F}}  % "false"
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
$\begin{array}{ *{8}{c} }
\toprule
B & F & P & C & B \lor F & P \lor C & \neg(F \land C) & \neg(B \land P)\\
\midrule
\T & \T & \T & \T & \T & \T & \F & \F \\ 
\T & \T & \T & \F & \T & \T & \T & \F \\
\T & \T & \F & \T & \T & \T & \F & \T \\
\T & \T & \F & \F & \T & \F & \T & \T \\[1ex]
\T & \F & \T & \T & \T & \T & \T & \F \\
\T & \F & \T & \F & \T & \T & \T & \F \\
\T & \F & \F & \T & \T & \T & \T & \T \\
\T & \F & \F & \F & \T & \F & \T & \T \\[1ex]
\F & \T & \T & \T & \T & \T & \F & \T \\
\F & \T & \T & \F & \T & \T & \T & \T \\
\F & \T & \F & \T & \T & \T & \F & \T \\
\F & \T & \F & \F & \T & \F & \T & \T \\[1ex]
\F & \F & \T & \T & \F & \T & \T & \T \\
\F & \F & \T & \F & \F & \T & \T & \T \\
\F & \F & \F & \T & \F & \T & \T & \T \\
\F & \F & \F & \T & \F & \T & \T & \T \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 22):

In my case it happened because I didn't declare the right number of columns

example:

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}

Comment: This answer saved me a lot of time searching for semantic problems with longtabu, tabu and so on. After all it was only a simple mistake.

Answer (score 11):

#### 2017 update

Since `xintexpr 1.1 (2014/10/28)` it is preferred to use `||` and `&&`, the single `|` and `&` may change meaning from their current ones as Boolean `or` resp.  `and`. One can also use the keywords `'or'` resp. `'and'` (quotes mandatory). Answer updated to anticipate possible future change of meaning of single `|` and `&` infix operators.

---

Perhaps you wish the table to be automatically filled in?

Update adds code for `1ex` vertical skip every four rows thing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xintexpr}

\newcommand\T{\textrm{T}}  % "true"
\newcommand\F{\textrm{F}}  % "false"

\newcommand\TF[1]{\if1#1\T\else\F\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering

$\begin{array}{ *{8}{c} }
\toprule
B & F & P & C & B \lor F & P \lor C & \neg(F \land C) & \neg(B \land P)\\
\midrule
\xintFor #1 in {1,0}\do {%
  \xintFor #2 in {1,0}\do {%
    \xintFor #3 in {1,0}\do {%
      \xintFor #4 in {1,0}\do {%
 \TF#1 & \TF#2 & \TF#3 & \TF#4 &
 \xintifboolexpr {#1 || #2}{\T}{\F}& 
 \xintifboolexpr {#3 || #4}{\T}{\F} &
 \xintifboolexpr {not(#2 && #4)}{\T}{\F} & 
 \xintifboolexpr {not(#1 && #3)}{\T}{\F} \\ 
 }}}}
\bottomrule
\end{array}$

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: truth table]

With extra skips:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xintexpr}

\newcommand\T{\textrm{T}}  % "true"
\newcommand\F{\textrm{F}}  % "false"

\newcommand\TF[1]{\if1#1\T\else\F\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
$\begin{array}{ *{8}{c} }
\toprule
B & F & P & C & B \lor F & P \lor C & \neg(F \land C) & \neg(B \land P)\\
\midrule
\xintFor #1 in {1,0}\do {%
  \xintFor #2 in {1,0}\do {%
    \xintFor #3 in {1,0}\do {%
      \xintFor #4 in {1,0}\do {%
 \TF#1 & \TF#2 & \TF#3 & \TF#4 &
 \xintifboolexpr {#1 || #2}{\T}{\F}& 
 \xintifboolexpr {#3 || #4}{\T}{\F} &
 \xintifboolexpr {not(#2 && #4)}{\T}{\F} & 
 \xintifboolexpr {#3 || #4}% every four, add 1ex space
     {\xintifboolexpr {not(#1 && #3)}{\T}{\F}\\}
     {\xintifboolexpr {not(#1 && #3)}{\T}{\F}\\[1ex]}
 }}}}
\noalign{\addvspace{-1ex}}% compensate the last 1ex vskip
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: truth table with extra vertical spaces]

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen because I copy pasted some stuff from another table in my document, was using the following syntax to make a horizontal line under only part of the table:

```
\\\cline{2-3}
```

I copy pasted

```
\\\cline{2-5}
```

from a table with more columns, and it gave this error until I corrected it.

Comment: This is probably a solution to a different problem that results in the same error. Technically it doesn't answer this question, since the OP doesn't user `\cline`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `|c|c|c|` to `crcrcr`. I made this table as follows.

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{crcrcrcrcrcrcrcr}
\hline
B & F & P & C &  $B \lor F$ & $P \lor C$ & $\neg(F \land C)$ & $\neg(B \land P)$ \\
\hline
T & T & T & T & T & T & F & F \\ % Error l.37 T & T & T & T & T & T & F & F \\ ?
T & T & T & F & T & T & T & F \\
T & T & F & T & T & T & F & T \\
T & T & F & F & T & F & T & T \\
T & F & T & T & T & T & T & F \\ 
T & F & T & F & T & T & T & F \\
T & F & F & T & T & T & T & T \\
T & F & F & F & T & F & T & T \\
F & T & T & T & T & T & F & T \\
F & T & T & F & T & T & T & T \\
F & T & F & T & T & T & F & T \\
F & T & F & F & T & F & T & T \\
F & F & T & T & F & T & T & T \\
F & F & T & F & F & T & T & T \\
F & F & F & T & F & T & T & T \\
F & F & F & T & F & T & T & T \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Note: For top and bottom rule, I used `\hline` command