# LaTeX table checker?

Tags: tables, errors

Is there a piece of code out there for checking that tables have the correct number of columns *before* trying to compile? I've searched for this error message a million times:

> Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

And I always end up on this page:
[Table - Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203173/table-extra-alignment-tab-has-been-changed-to-cr)

It's not as straightforward as counting the number of `&` characters in each line and comparing to `\begin{tabular}`, because sometimes I have tables with lines like this `\multicolumn{3}` or this `\begin{tabular}{l rr @{\hspace{1em}} r}`.

I could write the code myself, but I'm sure I would miss a lot of things. Has anyone written a table checker? Is this more of a meta question? Thanks!

Comment: In texstudio too many `&` will be marked in red.

Comment: to do a full job would require a full tex engine to expand user markup so it isn't clear whether such a thing ca exist other than a simplistic check of `&` that would catch some cases but give spurious warnings in others

Comment: Often all the & of a table row are not in the same line of code

Comment: Not sure if it would help, but latexindent aligns ampersands (usually) which can help

Answer (score 2):

Life is easier if you are using `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package, where number of columns is automatically determined by table contents.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]